# Direct and indirect CP violation

Tags: particle-physics, cp-violation

Experimentally, what is the difference between *direct* and *indirect* CP violation?

An example of **indirect** CP violation is:
$$ \Gamma(\overline{B}^0 \rightarrow B^0) \neq \Gamma(B^0 \rightarrow  \overline{B}^0 ).$$

An example of **direct** CP violation is:

$$ \Gamma(\overline{B}^0 \rightarrow \overline{K}) \neq \Gamma(B^0 \rightarrow  K ).$$

If we start with a pool of $\overline{B}^0$ mesons, leave them for a bit and then come back and count how many $B^0$ have appeared, we can get $ \Gamma(\overline{B}^0 \rightarrow B^0) $. Similarly, with a pool of $B^0$ mesons we can get $\Gamma(B^0 \rightarrow  \overline{B}^0 )$.

So what is **indirect** about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference, I think, is that $\overline B{}^0 \to B^0$ and $B^0 \to \overline B{}^0$ are inverse processes, and so a difference between them can be ascribed to broken $CP$ symmetry, as you say, or to broken time-reversal symmetry. Only with the additional (strongly motivated) assumption that $CPT$ is an exact symmetry of nature can you definitely say that the two interpretations are identical.

By contrast, $\overline B{}^0 \to \overline K$ is time-conjugate to $\overline K\to\overline B{}^0$. So any difference between $\overline B{}^0 \to \overline K$ and $B^0 \to K$ *cannot* be blamed on $T$-violation, and is therefore a "direct" probe of $CP$.